# Custom JSF component renderer: how to render HTML around another element

Tags: jsf, encoding, hyperlink, custom-component, custom-renderer

I have 2 elements, banana and an outputText, where banana is a custom JSF component and in banana renderer, I would like to generate HTML enclosing the specified element.

xhtml:

```
<h:outputText id="theApple" value="This is an Apple" />
.
.
.
<my:banana for="theApple" link="http://www.banana.com" />
```

bananaRenderer(encloses the target element in anchor links):

```
@Override
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter responseWriter = context.getResponseWriter();
    Banana banana = Banana.class.cast(component);
    responseWriter.startElement("a", null);
    responseWriter.writeAttribute("id", banana.getClientId(context), null);
    responseWriter.writeAttribute("href", banana.getLink(), null);
}

@Override
public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter responseWriter = context.getResponseWriter();
    Banana banana = Banana.class.cast(component);
    responseWriter.endElement("a");
}
```

What I want to achieve:

```
<a href="http://www.banana.com">This is an Apple</a>
.
.
.
```

As you can see I want to encode not on the banana component but on the element it targets using "for" attribute.
The closest example I saw is PrimeFaces tooltip, but I can't quite grasp how it utilizes the "for" attribute.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/tooltip/tooltipOptions.xhtml#

If someone can point me to the right direction, it would really be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manipulate the component tree during [`PreRenderViewEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/PreRenderViewEvent.html). During that moment, all components are guaranteed to be present in the tree, and it's guaranteed safe to manipulate the component tree by adding/moving/removing components in the tree. You can find other components in the tree by [`UIComponent#findComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent-java.lang.String-). You can traverse the component tree using [`UIComponent#getParent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getParent--) and [`UIComponent#getChildren()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getChildren--). The `getChildren()` returns a mutable list which is guaranteed safe to manipulate during `PreRenderViewEvent`.

Given that you'd like to wrap a given component with a hyperlink, and there exist already a JSF hyperlink component, the `<h:outputLink>`, it's easier to extend and reuse it to keep the code simple and DRY. Here's a basic kickoff example:

```
@FacesComponent(createTag=true)
public class Banana extends HtmlOutputLink implements SystemEventListener {

    public Banana() {
        getFacesContext().getViewRoot().subscribeToViewEvent(PreRenderViewEvent.class, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isListenerForSource(Object source) {
        return source instanceof UIViewRoot;
    }

    @Override
    public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        String forClientId = (String) getAttributes().get("for");

        if (forClientId != null) {
            UIComponent forComponent = findComponent(forClientId);
            List<UIComponent> forComponentSiblings = forComponent.getParent().getChildren();
            int originalPosition = forComponentSiblings.indexOf(forComponent);
            forComponentSiblings.add(originalPosition, this);
            getChildren().add(forComponent);
        }
    }

}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:my="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/component"
>
    <h:head>
        <title>SO question 38197494</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputText id="theApple" value="This is an Apple" />
        <my:banana for="theApple" value="http://www.banana.com" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Do note that explicit `children.remove()` call is not necessary when you already perform a `children.add()`. It will automatically take care about the child's parent.

Comment: Your solution works well as long as theApple comes first. Nonetheless, thank you.

Comment: I've fixed the code in answer to cover the other case as well. Nonetheless, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand the problem, you want to define 2 separate JSF components which produce common HTML code. One of possible solutions (as presented @BalusC) is component tree manipulation, but this is almost the same as to define in xhtml in a more natural way:

```
<my:banana link="http://www.banana.com">
    <h:outputText value="This is an Apple" />
</my:banana>
```

If for some needs you want to (re)render components referenced via `for`-attribute, I suggest to use javascript for DOM manipulations on the client side. You just need to define `script` tag in your `banana` renderer with appropriate javascript code:

```
@Override
public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    writer.startElement("script", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("type", "text/javascript", null);
    // find DOM-element by 'for'-attribute, and wrap it with a hyperlink 
    writer.endElement("script");
}
```

This is nearly how Primefaces tooltip built.

The benefit is that `banana` renderer does not aware of how `<h:outputText>` (or any other) will be rendered.

Comment: From the question: _"As you can see I want to encode not on the banana component but on the element it targets using "for" attribute. "_ so part one of your answer is not 'right'. And if you look at the code in the answer by @BalusC, you'll see that it is not aware either of how the outputText is rendered. So the second part of your second answer is not an 'enhancement'